# Android - View inflation messes up fragment transaction animation

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment, layout-inflater

I have some fragments where the inner views are inflated dynamically and added to a linearlayout to sort of form something similar to a list view. This works fine on a high end device but on mid to lower level devices there is very notice-able lag in the animation and sometimes the animation gets skipped altogether. Ive tried googling around for a bit and havent come across anything specific when it comes to transition animations in relation to inflating views and tips on how to handle dynamic view inflation during such a process.

So to recap....A user pushes a button, a fragment comes into view, the views dynamically inflate and, the animation lags or gets skipped. Id really like to make everything smooth if possible.

EDIT: some example code

```
public static void addPersonRow(PersonObject po){

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
    params.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
    final View view = IncidentReport_v2.ir2.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ir_involved_people_row, null);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setTag(po.originalName);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ir_involved_ppl_add_row_rl);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ir_involved_ppl_name_txt);
    name.setText(po.firstName+" "+po.lastName);

    ImageButton open = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ir_involved_ppl_reopen_btn);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("personObj", po);
    open.setTag(b);
    name.setTag(b);
    rl.setTag(b);

    OnClickListener openClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pplAddFrag = new IR_PeopleInvolved_AddForm_Fragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable("existingPerson", (Bundle)v.getTag());
            pplAddFrag.setArguments(b);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = IncidentReport_v2.ir2.getSupportFragmentManager();     
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce_out, R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce_out);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.ir_main_frame, pplAddFrag, "pplAddFrag");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("pplAddFrag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();      

            IncidentReport_v2.theMenu.removeItem(R.id.incident_report_save);
            IncidentReport_v2.ir2.invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }
    };

    open.setOnClickListener(openClick);
    name.setOnClickListener(openClick);
    rl.setOnClickListener(openClick);

    ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ir_involved_ppl_delete_btn);
    delete.setTag(po);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pplHolder.removeView(view);
            IncidentReport_v2.people.remove((PersonObject)v.getTag());
            IR_InvolvedFragment.pplCounterTxt.setText(IncidentReport_v2.people.size()+"");
        }
    });

    pplHolder.addView(view);

    if(!IncidentReport_v2.people.contains(po)){
        IncidentReport_v2.people.add(po);
    }

    IR_InvolvedFragment.pplTxt.setTextColor(IncidentReport_v2.ir2.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    IR_InvolvedFragment.pplCounterTxt.setText(IncidentReport_v2.people.size()+"");

}
```

This gets called inside of a for loop depending on how many personObjects I have

Comment: we ... need ... code . You didn't recap anything because there was no code to recap!

Comment: Sorry had to chop it up a bit but thats basically what Im doing at the time of the fragment transition/transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) don't make the method static (so you can access fields for more optimisations later)

2) cache the layout inflater so you don't have to get it for each row

3) if you get the view from XML may as well set the margins and weight in the XML

4) create the Bundle off the UI thread and set it at the last moment or as a callback

5) Create your Fragment elsewhere, use the same fragment each time onclick is pressed use the `FragmentManager` for this, a callback will be more light weight

6) you set three onclick listeners to do the same thing, can you not just delegate the ImageView clicks up to the parent i.e. only set the click on the relative layout

7) After all the above, the FragmentTransaction is the slowest thing, might want to look at changing it for a customview and just use visible & gone in the onClick with layout animation

give some of that a go

Comment: Cool thanks for the suggestions I know those should help a bit. Once I mess with them a bit Ill post back.

Comment: Further, do not a start a transaction for every fragment you're adding, add them all with a single `commit`- this alone will solve most of your problems.

Comment: But what if my activity potentially uses close to 20 different fragments?

Comment: You said it was a ListView with children? Are you saying you have 20 different children, they must have something in common, sounds like a refactor is needed

Comment: Apologies, I retract my comment about the single transaction - I thought every row was already a fragment.